# Debugging in visual studio release application

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have a release version of the application(which needs some batch files in order to install and run). I have a copy of source code with me. In order to see path of every event(to understand the program), what I am doing as of now is installing the application, and at the same time building my source code, and then copy all the dlls and pdbs(so that debugger can map to my code) from my debug folder to program files and then running the app. As I have placed diagnostics.debugger.launch in my source code, I have been able to debug my version. 
 I am doing this because, I can't execute and test the project directly from my bin\debug, as it has some dependencies(batch file parameters) hence I am installing released version. I have to find out every event path in my code(as I am new to this company and also .NET). Is there an easier way(like intellitrace... is that going to help in my case?) thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you clarify what you mean by "find out every execution path"?  Is this an assignment you've been given?  Or are you doing this to get more familiar with the software?  Are you trying to determine the [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) of the application?

Comment: Talk to a member of the team, they already know how to debug the app.  We don't.  Never be shy about asking for help from your team members, they *want* you to get up to speed as fast as possible.  Asking for their help doesn't make you sound inept, it makes you sound eager to learn and become an effective member of the team.  That's a good thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!  Much more information would be helpful.  What is the program doing, what problem are you trying to solve, etc...

As far as tracking the execution path, there are lots of ways to do what you want.  Just a few suggestions:

- Log the startup inputs and debug the program in your development environment with those same inputs.  May not work depending on other external dependencies.
- Log the entry to every method to a file.  This will let you see the execution path.  This is very tacky to implement the old-fashioned way, but you could use something like the [**OnMethodBoundaryAspect**](http://doc.postsharp.net/##T_PostSharp_Aspects_OnMethodBoundaryAspect) from the free version of [**PostSharp**](http://www.postsharp.net/) to write the logging code once and reuse it as needed on a given method.
- Use an instrumentation platform like [**Gibraltar**](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/) to get some visibility into what is going on.
- Use a Trace Listener to track your event execution.  Look at Trace.Listeners.Add().  Once you create a listener you can call Trace.Write or Trace.WriteLine to add information to the trace.  This involves a lot of manually entering trace information into your methods, but if you're desperate, you can do it.  I'd prefer an Aspect-Oriented solution like PostSharp, but you may not have that option for whatever reason.

**Quick sample:** (Again, this approach not recommended...)

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace TrackingExecutionPath
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myFile = File.Create(@"C:\Application.log");
            Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(myFile));

            Trace.WriteLine("Starting up");
            var tracer = new Tracer();
            tracer.TraceMeOnce();
            Trace.WriteLine("Wrapping up");

            Trace.Flush();
        }

    }

    internal class Tracer
    {
        public void TraceMeAgain()
        {
            Trace.IndentLevel++;
            Trace.WriteLine("Entering TraceMeAgain");
            Trace.WriteLine("Doing some work.");
            Trace.WriteLine("Exiting TraceMeAgain");
            Trace.IndentLevel--;
        }

        public void TraceMeOnce()
        {
            Trace.IndentLevel++;
            Trace.WriteLine("Entering TraceMeOnce");
            Trace.WriteLine("Doing some work.");
            TraceMeAgain();
            Trace.WriteLine("Exiting TraceMeOnce");
            Trace.IndentLevel--;
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample output:**

Starting up
    Entering TraceMeOnce
    Doing some work.
        Entering TraceMeAgain
        Doing some work.
        Exiting TraceMeAgain
    Exiting TraceMeOnce
Wrapping up

Comment: Thanks for accepting.  I'd be curious to know more about your problem and the approach you wind up taking.  Let us know if you have a moment.